# if internet getway of aws default VPC accidently deleted, how to add

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Internet Getway of Default VPC deleted by mistake but after creating manually Internet getway also EC2 launched under default VPC not accessible from internet, please suggest how to fix this

created manually Internet getway and attached to Default VPC

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new IG, and add in the default routing table the route 0.0.0.0/0 to the new IG.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, First deleted the default VPC and created new default VPC, in VPC section in the action dropdown got a link to create a default VPC then automatically IG created with new default VPC.